# Returning first level tag in JOOX

Tags: java, xml, xpath, joox

I've following xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.sndbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>joox-test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
      <artifactId>joox</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>15.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Now I want to find **version** tag, but only on the root level of the document (project version = 1.0.0). When i use `find("version")` it works like `xpath("//version")` and returns tags from whole document, and I need equivalent of the `xpath("version")` method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options to fetch the /project/version tag:

```
$(doc).xpath("/project/version");
$(doc).child("version"); // matches the first
$(doc).children("version"); // matches all
```